# grails DataSource.groovy refer bean for decoding password

Tags: grails

Referring [GRAILS-3620](http://web.archive.org/web/20120826072909/http://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-3620), we need to specify a class with static methods to decode the encrypted password in `DataSource` config.
For `passwordEncryptionCodec` property, is it possible to refer to a bean defined in `resources.xml` or any other grails bean definition files?

For ex: having a decrypted Properties bean in `resoures.xml` or groovy, can I refer to this bean to pull the decrypted password? When I attempted doing this, bean resolution failed during grails startup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think this will be possible.

The reason for this is the lifecycle (startup) of a Spring/Grails application requires that the DataSource be parsed while setting up the Spring application context. As such, making reference to a bean in the application context isn't going to be valid because the application context hasn't finished being created.

The fact the JIRA issue indicates how to use **static methods** only underscores this since they have no requirement that the application context be fully initialized.